# Build Rest API using tell

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to figure out a good way of creating REST API using akka and akka-http. Based on the docs, request/reply is not the best solution for inter-actor communication. So my question is how can I achieve something similar to this snippet using tell?

```
for {
    randomNumber <- (actor1 ? GetRandomNumber).mapTo[Int]
    randomString <- (actor2 ? GetRandomString).mapTo[String]
  } yield s"Random String: $randomString, Random Number: $randomNumber"
```

Comment: Is this code suppose to be inside a http route or inside another actor?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc inside another actor

Comment: Do you need to get the data from two different actors and proceed only when both actors returned the result back?

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can incapsulate a state that gathers responses from other actors and process it when it is fully provided.

To explain this in code, consider following example

```scala
case class State(string: Option[String], int: Option[Int])

class CombiningActor(stringActor: ActorRef, intActor: ActorRef)
    extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = { case _ =>
    stringActor ! "Get Random String"
    intActor ! "Get Random Int"
    context.become(onMessage(State(string = None, int = None)))
  }

  private def onMessage(state: State): Receive = {
    case msg: String =>
      val newState = state.copy(string = Option(msg))
      whenSateFullyProvided(newState)
      context.become(onMessage(newState))
    case msg: Int =>
      val newState = state.copy(int = Option(msg))
      whenSateFullyProvided(newState)
      context.become(onMessage(newState))
  }

  private def whenSateFullyProvided(state: State): Unit = {
    if (state.string.nonEmpty && state.int.nonEmpty) {
      // Process the state here
    }
  }
}
```

The state accumulation is happening with the help of `context.become` which

> Changes the Actor's behavior to become the new 'Receive'
> (PartialFunction[Any, Unit]) handler. Replaces the current behavior on
> the top of the behavior stack.

Please note that behaviour switches are more complex to handle if your actor should process other messages at the same time.

If you don't want to use `context.become`, `private var state: State` as variable field for `CombiningActor` can be also used to achieve the same result.

As a final note, please do not use primitive types for messages in untyped actors. It's hard to understand the code as well as might have problems if two different actors send same primitive types around.